# Change row height in listActivity when pressed

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I have created a `ListActivity` class, with a custom Adapter.

Rows are simple: `TextView` and a `Button`.

Implemented `getView` method is as below:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    TextView tV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tV.setText(MY_LIST[position]);

    return convertView;
}
```

Now I want that each row, when pressed, dynamically add another button to itself, below the others components, and that consequently, the row height is increased.

How can I perform this steps?

Answer (score 0):

New button should be hidden by default. When user clicked on row your handler makes something like `mHiddenButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Comment: If a button is not visible, however row consider the height. Row is simply higher.

Comment: Set `android:visibility="gone"` to exclude component from layout calculations